# How to disable/ hide delete button for column in list in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, content-type, site-column, pnp-powershell

I have a calculated field in my custom list. I want to disable or hide delete button on this field edit page. I want specific users not able delete this column in a list but still be able to edit/ delete other columns in the same list. Please see below screenshot for field:

[image: filed disable]

I have tried below things:

- Checked adding column as site column and added in content type. Then associate content type in list. But it is not restricting delete.
- Checked SharePoint Online Powershell. But not able to set sealed property for this column.
- I can't apply permission break as I want users to be able to manage other columns in list

Is there any other way that we can do this? Is PNP-Powershell has any cmdlets that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option ([strongly unsupported by Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/portal-branding#what-not-to-do)) is to add custom Javascript (JS) in masterpage file, targeting this specific button for this specific field:

1) create JS file and store in SP --> code alters target button by hiding it or deleting (or how is more convenient for You)

2) create custom masterpage based on original (never-ever-ever edit the original masterpage)

3) insert link to previously created JS file

4) enjoy.